# Can not drop FOREIGN KEY in Maria DB

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, mariadb

show create table USERS;
  And i will get that result .

```
    CREATE TABLE `USERS` (
  `UR_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `DEPT_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DN_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_BY` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `LAST_UPDATED_BY` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `LAST_UPDATED_DT` datetime NOT NULL,
  `UR_LOGIN_NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `TRANS_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UR_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Uk11` (`UR_LOGIN_NAME`),
  KEY `SYS_C0018877` (`UR_ID`),
  KEY `SYS_C0018878` (`DEPT_ID`),
  KEY `SYS_C0018879` (`DN_ID`),
  **KEY `SYS_C0018880` (`CREATED_BY`),**
  KEY `SYS_C0018881` (`LAST_UPDATED_BY`),
  KEY `SYS_C0018882` (`LAST_UPDATED_DT`),
  KEY `SYS_C0018883` (`UR_LOGIN_NAME`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_USERS_2` FOREIGN KEY (`DN_ID`) REFERENCES `DESIGNATION` (`DN_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Now i want to drop foreign key CREATED_BY and i run 
 **ALTER TABLE USERS DROP FOREIGN KEY SYS_C0018880;**
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './dbname/USERS' to './dbname/#sql2-3ea-2c' (errno: 152)

Also I have used

**ALTER TABLE USERS DROP FOREIGN KEY CREATED_BY;**

But i again got same error

Error on rename of './dbname/USERS' to './dbname/#sql2-3ea-2c' (errno: 152)

Please any one share how can i drop this foreign key and if possible please share what is KEY `SYS_C0018880` (`CREATED_BY`) . I knew this key is foreign key because on desc table_name i got this result;

| DN_ID           | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
**| CREATED_BY      | varchar(45)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |**
| LAST_UPDATED_BY | varchar(45)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| LAST_UPDATED_DT | datetime     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is file(s) #sql2-3ea-2c* in data directory and/or table with such name in internal InnoDB dictionary. That would prevent any ALTER operation on USERS table.. Search google for 'removing orphaned innodb tables' for instructions reg. that

Answer (score 6):

By default MariaDB appends _ibfk to the name of the foreign keys if you do not specify it.So, please use the following code format to drop foreign keys where you have not specified foreign key name:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP FOREIGN KEY foreign_key_ibfk;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the key name not foreign key

```
 ALTER TABLE USERS DROP KEY SYS_C0018880
```

Comment: I want to drop  **KEY `SYS_C0018880` (`CREATED_BY`),**  key , I do not want drop foreign key  "DN_ID"